# Keep NerdTree open when opening a file initially?

Tags: nerdtree

How do I keep nerdtree open when I first open a file. At the moment it is open from the second time onwards. However, when I first open something it closes and I have to manually open it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer for this here:
https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/494

Instead of opening with vim . opening just with vim solves the problem.

Comment: but, if I get this right, you have to first put this two lines in your vimrc - first line:
`autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1` and second line: `autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTreeToggle | endif`  see: https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree/blame/1c0d9efe6c10c42815782e6a3609a73a335ec46b/README.markdown#L94